# How can I set an overlay network within docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I try to bring up a docker compose file with an overlay network, I get the following error:

> Creating network "esswarm_scarfelastic" with driver "overlay" ERROR:
>   driver name: if driver is specified name is required

Generated with this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
networks:
  scarfelastic:
    driver: overlay
```

This may be a bug, since if I specify 'bridge' as the network driver, no 'specified name' is required.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the driver type? By default, the networks are all created as overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need the very latest docker-compose 1.9.0 which has a [release note including](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/b570cba96532705a0decb54bf6dcebd7151df1b5/CHANGELOG.md):

> Fixed an issue where Compose would incorrectly detect a configuration mismatch for overlay network

See [issue 3845](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3845) and [PR 4098](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/4098).
[Issue 3575](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3575) shows a possible working syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, its create overlay network in swarm

networks:
   - custom_network
networks:
 custom_network:
  driver: overlay